# Unable to install python package pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I am trying to install pandas.

```
PS C:\Users\koffl\OneDrive\Desktop\Firefuzz-main> pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-2.1.1.tar.gz (4.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      + meson setup C:\Users\koffl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gstzaanz\pandas_874e76d2e9894e969f5b0eca7649e2f3 C:\Users\koffl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gstzaanz\pandas_874e76d2e9894e969f5b0eca7649e2f3\.mesonpy-3j8mbjdj\build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --vsenv --native-file=C:\Users\koffl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gstzaanz\pandas_874e76d2e9894e969f5b0eca7649e2f3\.mesonpy-3j8mbjdj\build\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.2.1
      Source dir: C:\Users\koffl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gstzaanz\pandas_874e76d2e9894e969f5b0eca7649e2f3
      Build dir: C:\Users\koffl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gstzaanz\pandas_874e76d2e9894e969f5b0eca7649e2f3\.mesonpy-3j8mbjdj\build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: pandas
      Project version: 2.1.1

      ..\..\meson.build:2:0: ERROR: Could not parse vswhere.exe output

      A full log can be found at C:\Users\koffl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gstzaanz\pandas_874e76d2e9894e969f5b0eca7649e2f3\.mesonpy-3j8mbjdj\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

this is the error. Do you know how i can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a permission issue looks like your in one drive. Try making python env and doing `pip install pandas` in environment

Comment: Hi, don't forget to convert this into a *comment* when you get commenting rights.